# Want to Learn magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2, xml, phtml, system-config, magento2.3.5-p1

I am Working as PHP Developer and want to learn about magento 2.3.5 from scratch so can anyone having material related to magento 2.3.5 then please send me for self learning and any demo of modules as well as theme development can please send me.

Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get from magento official websites to learn magento 2.3.5 from the scratch